# Access a global variable from any app controller

Tags: ember.js

I need to use a global variable (user context, available from all the code)
I have read some posts regarding this topic but I do not have a clear answer.

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
  LOG_TRANSITIONS: true,
  currentUser: null
});
```

1. Is it a good practice to set the currentUser global variable in the App object ?
2. How to update and access the currentUser property from all the controllers used in the app ?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

> Is it a good practice to set the currentUser global variable in the App object ?

No, this is not a good practice. You should avoid using global variables. The framework does a lot to make this possible - if you find yourself thinking a global variable is the best solution it's a sign that something should be refactored. In most cases the right place is in a controller. For example, currentUser could be:

```
//a property of application controller
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  currentUser: null
});

//or it's own controller
App.CurrentUserController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({});
```

> How to update and access the currentUser property from all the controllers used in the app ?

Use the `needs` property. Let's say you've declared currentUser as a property of ApplicationController. It can be accessed from PostsController like this:

```
App.PostsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend{(
  needs: ['application'],
  currentUser: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.application.currentUser'),
  addPost: function() {
    console.log('Adding a post for ', this.get('currentUser.name'));
  }
)}
```

If you need to access currentUser from a view/template, just use `needs` to make it accessible via the local controller. And if you need it from a route, use the route's controllerFor method.

Comment: I have few application level boolean properties, and those properties will be used in almost all the views/templates. If i define them in `applicationController` then i have to define `needs` property in all the controller. If i define them in App then no need of `needs`. Any thought on this?

Comment: I can see an argument for setting a few boolean properties at the App level, like ember itself defines LOG_TRANSITIONS. Anything more complicated should def be in it's own controller. If you are in a situation where you want one controller to be available in all the others, you can use an initializer to inject it into the others. See http://mcdowall.info/posts/ember-application-initializers/ for an example that makes `CurrentUserController` available as the `currentUser` property of all controllers. Could easily do the same with a ConfigController.

Comment: Ember.Computed should be Ember.computed

Comment: And I'm getting an error running this... Apparently the second colon currentUser: <<< throws an error in the javascript console

Comment: @jsetting32 This post should be updated to say:
`currentUser: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.Application.currentUser'),`

Comment: @psycodrumfreak so simply doing something like `this.get('currentUser', "newValue')` in the child controller will automatically bind and push changes to all of the ancestor controllers?

Comment: does `needs` make the controller accessible to controllers only, or could it have been all four combinations of route and controller (child route needs application controller, child route needs application route, child controller needs application route, child controller needs application controller)? If you do have a grandchild controller do you do `needs: ['application'] or 'needs: ['<the direct child of application>']`?

Comment: Update: Using `needs` to access controllers is deprecated. Use the following two lines inside the `PostsController` instead: `applicationController: Ember.inject.controller('application'),` and `currentUser: Ember.computed.alias('applicationController.currentUser')`. See http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.inject.html#method_controller.

Comment: @MikeGrassotti - your blog post link 404's - I think this is the new URL... http://mcdowall.info/ember-application-initializers/