# Waiting for models to load before rendering app in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have a number of different application-level models — i.e., current user, current account, etc. — that I want to load before rendering my application. How and where should this be done? [This question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16878473/access-a-global-variable-from-any-app-controller) helped a lot, but it doesn't cover the async aspect.

The following code accomplishes what I want, but loading the models in `beforeModel` (to take advantage of it waiting for the promise to resolve) doesn't seem right. Should I even be loading these models in `ApplicationRoute`?

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  currentAccount: null
});

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  beforeModel: function () {
    var self = this;

    return App.Account.find(...).then(function (account) {
      self.controllerFor('application').set('currentAccount', account);
    });
  }
});
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6):

The trick is to return a promise from the route's model method.
This will cause the router to transition into App.LoadingRoute route, until the promise resolves (which can be used for loading indication bars/wheels etc.)
When the promise resolves, the App.LoadingRoute will be deactivated, and the original route's setupController method will be called.
This works for ember-data promises, JQuery's $.ajax promises and ember-model's fetch promises.
Just make sure you return the actual model after resolving the promise.
This can also be a good place to handle errors if the promise is rejected - but I'll leave that to some other question.

As for where you should load your models - that is dependent on your app's usage.
Usually you would load a model where the URL indicates you need that model - a rule of thumb would be the indication of a model ID in the URL.
This of course changes if you need to prefetch some data.

And now for some code:

```
App.SomeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function(params){
       return App.SomeModel.fetch(params.model_id).then(function(modelData){
           // it is better to return the actual model here, and not the promise itself
           return App.SomeModel.find(params.model_id);
       });

   },
   setupController: function(controller, model){
       controller.set("model", model);
       // do some controller setup here - can be omitted if no setup is needed
       // this will run only after the promise has been resolved.
   }
});

App.LoadingRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        activate: function(){
            this._super();
            // add some loading indication here
        },
        deactivate: function(){
            this._super();
            // remove loading indication
        }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but you don't really answer where I should load application-level models that I need everywhere. In other words, models that aren't dependent on the URL.

Comment: if you need them upfront, you can use the Ember.Application's init method

Comment: I can't seem to find any indication that it waits for a promise to resolve. Can you explain in more detail? Thanks.

Comment: When you return a promise from the model method of a route, the router will temporarily transition into LoadingRoute (you should define a nice LoadingRoute with a spinning loading wheel or something like that), until the promise is resolved.
When the promise is resolved, it will go back to your route and run the setupController as expected.
you can find an example here:
http://jsbin.com/axarop/47/edit
and some reference here:
https://gist.github.com/machty/5723945

Answer (score 6):

You want to preload data/models to initialize your application, and feel beforeModel is incorrect?

Sounds like you need an application initializer!

Your friend in this instance:

**App.deferReadiness();** // halt progress of application until all instances of this call (ie: multiple initializers) are matched by an instance the following call:

**App.advanceReadiness();** // consider this to be equivalent to a promise resolve call.

1) From you looking up the user directly, modifying where mentioned to suit your app setup:

```
Ember.Application.initializer({
    name: 'loadUser',
    after: 'store',
    initialize: function(container, app) {
        // modify this following to suit how you're determining the account
        var url = 'user/' + currentAccount;
        // tell the app to pause loading until advanceReadiness is declared
        app.deferReadiness();

        // load from JSON 
        Ember.$.getJSON('url').then(function(json) {

            var store = container.lookup('store:main');
            store.load(app.User, json);

            // tell app to start progressing again
            app.advanceReadiness();
        });
    }
});
```

2) Through meta tag:

```
Ember.Application.initializer({
    name: 'currentUser'
    after: 'store',

    initialize: function(container, app) {
        app.deferReadiness();

        $(function() {
            // Look up an attribute in a meta tag
            var store      = container.lookup('store:main'),
                attributes = $('meta[name="current-user"]').attr('content');

            if (attributes) {
                var obj        = store.load(app.User, JSON.parse(attributes)),
                    user       = App.User.find(obj.id),
                    controller = container.lookup('controller:currentUser').set('content', user);

                container.typeInjection('controller', 'currentUser', 'controller:currentUser');
            }
            app.advanceReadiness();
        });
    }
});
```

3) Through Session data:

```
Ember.Application.initializer({
    name  : 'currentUser',
    after : 'session',
    initialize: function(container, app) {
        var controller = container.lookup('controller:currentUser');
        container.typeInjection('controller', 'currentUser', 'controller:currentUser');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get this work by using nested Promises and the afterModel method in the ApplicationRoute.

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

    model: function() {

        // load the reservation (a globally needed model)
        return App.Reservation.fetch().then(function(reservations) {
            return reservations.get('firstObject');
        });

    },

    afterModel: function() {

        // Load all other globally needed models
        var self = this;
        return App.Gender.fetch().then(function(genders) {
            self.controllerFor('application').set('genders', genders);
            return App.FilterAttribute.fetch().then(function(filterAttributes) {
                self.controllerFor('application').set('filterAttributes', filterAttributes);
                //return App.SomeOtherModel...
            });
        });

    },

    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        controller.set('reservation', model);
    }

});
```

Works just perfectly :-) The application remains in the LoadingRoute until all records are loaded. 
Note that I am using [Ember Model](https://github.com/ebryn/ember-model), but this should make no difference, it just have to return a Promise.