# Ember / Handlebars: Get Application controller in a handlebars helper function

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

How do I access the application controller (App.ApplicationController) from a handlebars helper function declared like so:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('actionButtons', function(context, options) {
    var thisUserId = context.content.get('userID');
    var thatUserId = // Somehow get the user ID from the ApplicationController model
    if (thisUserId == thatUserId) {
        // Do Something
    }
});
```

Much thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't access the controller directly, you pass in values from the controller into the helper.

Controller:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
     userId: 'foobar'
});
```

Template:

```
{{actionButtons userId}}
```

Helper:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('actionButtons', function(userId, options) {
    //userId now contains the userId from your controller
});
```

EDIT: I would suggest putting that information in a global variable like `App.Global.User` or something. But if you *really* need the controller in the function, you can look it up in the container:

```
var applicationController = App.__container__.lookup('controller:application');
```

Comment: I know, but I have an application-global user account that I'm checking the currently-enumerated userID against. Is there really no better way to do this besides passing in both userIDs to my method?

Comment: There's a slightly shorter way, although I'm not sure if it's better. I've updated my post.

Comment: What about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16878473/access-a-global-variable-from-any-app-controller)?  And even ignoring that, how do you even properly set an App global to point to a model record? `this.store.find('user', 1).then(function(result) {App.CurrentUser=result;});` doesn't persist in the application...To be honest, nothing about Ember's so-called "conventions" (which apparently change every couple of months) make sense to me.

Comment: Their conventions haven't changed at all since 1.0.  Your example there looks perfect, what do you mean by "doesn't persist in the application"?  App.Global isn't a real object, he's just giving an example.

Comment: Actually, it looks like it is persisting...but when I do a hard reload of the page, the registerBoundHelper function is always being called before the ApplicationRoute gets a chance to set App.CurrentUser

Comment: Also, how would you access App.CurrentUser via a handlebars template?

Comment: Handlebars only allows you to access values within the context given. So if you wanted to access a variable in every handlebars template, you would have to inject the value into every controller or view that has a template.

Comment: So then I am just better off putting it in the controller and doing the weird container lookup? This is what I mean about not understanding Ember's conventions. There seems to be no sane way to go about this, yet I'd imagine that it's a very common use-case.

Comment: Actually, there is a very specific reason that this _is_ a convention. Ideally, you shouldn't be accessing a single piece of data all throughout your view hierarchy. It should mainly be contained to just one or two routes. Given that, I would say that it's probably better to put the value in the controllers where you need it. Use the controller `needs` functionality and `Ember.alias` to have the same value in multiple controllers.